# Strictly positive values in normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to define a strictly positive range for normal distribution like I want to have a distribution in the range `(0,10)` with a certain `mu, sigma`?

Using `np.random.normal`, sometimes I get negative values which I don't want.

```
import numpy as np
I=np.random.normal(3, 10, size=(3,3))
```

Comment: By definition, a normal distribution takes values over all real numbers. But in practice, all values are located around the mean. Having only positive values makes no sense, can you be more precise? For example, you could have a normal distribution centered at 5, so that the values would roughly spawn between 0 and 10. However, depending on the sigma, you might have negative values sometimes.

Comment: Is it possible to have the mean in positive real space and have a constraint that no value goes below 0?

Comment: Yes, simply pick a random number, and if it's negative, pick again. But then, it's no longer a _normal_ distribution. But it looks a lot like it.

Comment: I can play around sigma with a center being at any positive real number.

Comment: In theory a normal distribution will always span on all real numbers (except if you take sigma=0, then it becomes a constant distribuion). You can play around with sigma by lowering it until your numbers all lie _in practice_ in a given range, however be aware that lowering sigma will make your distribution closer to a constant distribution.  If you're using a normal distribution with mu=5 and sigma=5/3, you have _approximately_ 99% chance that the drawn number lies in the interval [0, 10]

Comment: I want a high variance, so a higher sigma but again with the constraint that the mean is somewhere in positive real space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try 'scipy.stats.truncnorm' - quote **The standard form of this distribution is a standard normal truncated to the range**

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html